# Calculate Monthly Highest Selling Product - MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

[image]I am trying to figure out how to get the product with the highest sales per month using Excel. I'm new to excel and it's been a struggle understanding what formula to use.

Please help!

Comment: Without doing any math, the water pump will likely be the answer...

Comment: @findwindow Yeah, But not every month sold a water pump

Comment: the below answer with the pivot table is probably the best answer.  another nice output though could be a table with months across the top and products down the side and then use a heat map to show each month, would take some messing to get it right but would show more detail

Comment: @InjuredCoding - not particularly dynamic though (and ignores possibility of mulitple products per transaction). Not sure how well 'tied results' handled (?). see other soln courtesy yours sincerely for complete walkthrough ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Pivot Table to summarize the data.  Use these columns in your fields:

[image]

Click the dropdown arrow in the Product column, choose value filters, Top 10.  Choose top 1 by sum of sales:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!, I tried it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot(s) refer:

**Setup**

*Sample data (B:M) and unique product ID / unit cost list (O:Q)*

[image: Sample data and Unique Product List]

*Note: Unique product List ony required for Method 3 - see below*

---

Notice col M 'Sales' derived as Store cost / unit cost:

```
=F4:F29/INDEX(Q4:Q10,MATCH(D4:D29,P4:P10,0))
```

[image: Sales per transaction]

Only relevant if transactions comprise 1 or more sales of a given product (here, transactions 1001, 1008 comprise 3 pool covers and 4 pool domes resp.). This is covered under method 3 (can also be handled by method 1, albeit only the single product/trans is given in that example).

---

**Methods**

1. Pivot Table method - can handle 'single' or 'multi' product variations
2. Countifs method - only for 'single' product per trans
3. Sumifs method - as for pivot table method

---

**1. Pivot Table**

*(quick but not v. dynamic - i.e. requires refreshing)*

*a) Select the sample data, and click 'Analyse Data' in Home section of main ribbon:*

[image: Analyse Data]

*b) In the 'Ask a question about your data' search bar, type 'Which is the most common 'Product' each month?*

[image: Analyse Data]

*c) Select 'insert Pivot table'*

[image: Pivot Table with top product per month]

Notes:

- You may need to sort row labels if you want this to read chronologically Jan->Apr
- You can try different variations or select one of the suggestions to allow or other summaries, e.g. by $ sales / multi-product variation etc

---

**2. Max number of sales per month (1 sale per transaction)**
*requires Office 365 compatible version of Excel*

Obtain unique list of months:

```
=UNIQUE(B4:B29)
```

[image: Unique month list]

Obtain complete & unique lists for Product IDs each month, for unique lists, determine corresponding count of product IDs (countifs); then join the filtered list corresponding to product ids with max counts using text join -

```
=LET(x_,TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE($D$4:$D$29))),y_,TRANSPOSE(COUNTIFS($D$4:$D$29,TRANSPOSE(x_),$B$4:$B$29,S4)),TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(x_,--ISNUMBER(MATCH(y_,IFERROR(COLUMN(y_)/0,MAX(y_)),0)))))
```

[image: Option 2 - single product/transaction result]

---

**Option 3 - multi product/transaction**

*As for option 2 (Office 365, unique month, complete/unique lists, etc.) but now countifs replaced by sumifs, and col M (# sales, cf. *set up*) utilised:*

```
=LET(x_,TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE($D$4:$D$29))),y_,TRANSPOSE(SUMIFS($M$4#,$D$4:$D$29,TRANSPOSE(x_),$B$4:$B$29,S4)),TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(x_,--ISNUMBER(MATCH(y_,IFERROR(COLUMN(y_)/0,MAX(y_)),0)))))
```

[image: Multi-product sales per trans results]

Notes:

- Product codes 9822 (Jan) and 1002 (Feb) outrank other products returned by Option 2 due to multi-product sales (3 and 4 resp.).
- This method is most robust as it can be used to return Product Codes with the highest profit/commission etc. (simply by altering values in col M).
- E.g. setting col M = £Commission yields the following 'highest commission earning Products' each month:

[image: Product ID with highest $ commission each month]

In this case, Products 1002 and 1003 dominate - given their sales volumes and high unit costs (comm. assumed 20% flat across each product otherwise).

---

**General points**

*Notes:
Assuming you intended to insert table as follows:*

```
| A| B| C| D| E| F| G| H| I| J| K |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
|  Month |  Transaction Number |  Product Code |  Product |  Store Cost |  Sale Price |  Profit |  Commission |  First name |  Last name |  Sale Location  |
| Jan| 1001| 9822|  Pool Cover|  $58.30 |  $98.40 |  $40.10 | 8.02|  Charlie|  Barns|  NM |
```

i.e.

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Month | Transaction Number | Product Code | Product | Store Cost | Sale Price | Profit | Commission | First name | Last name | Sale Location |
| Jan | 1001 | 9822 | Pool Cover | $58.30 | $98.40 | $40.10 | 8.02 | Charlie | Barns | NM |

☺

---